# how to draw black screen during pause state in video view

Tags: android, multimedia

Hello
our tester want to stop function in video player.
so I add stop button and call seekto(0) and pause when user press stop key.

but I has one problem. videoview is not clear play screen.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using video view try media player present in android.mediaplayer.mediaplayer so when you need to stop the player you can just call mediaplayerobject.stop() and then mediaplayerobject.release() thats all it will be easy